# Update datatable with new request and add / remove columns

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying with jquery datatable. Actually i am able to trigger new ajax request with an external button using the below code.

```
currentSource = "/an http url/";                            
var table = $('#datatableid').DataTable();
table.ajax.url(currentSource).load();
```

The new request was successful but i do not see any table data.

Have attached screenshot for the same. [image: Datatable issue]

In the screenshot you can see the entries count too and even the count get changes when i try some searches in the search box. But i do not see the content. :(

And i would like to remove some column once request the request was completed. This is my second problem too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an javascript error in the console?

Comment: No. I dont get any errors. Instead the datatable shows a warning like "DataTables warning: table id=datatableid - Requested unknown parameter 'User' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4" -

Comment: I have modified the question.

Comment: The answer is updated. so please dont consider about my comments.

Comment: I think the information you've deleted was actually useful - I don't understand why you deleted it. The error is related to the fact that your column count is different after the initial load. You need to look into ways of handling this - maybe a column which is hidden when the data is null.

Comment: I too thought of the same, so what i did now is, i have triggered the same request, so there wont be any column mismatch and no warning messages. This is the reason that i have updated my info.  So now, On the full page load, the request was successful and i am able to see the table data. But when i trigger another request (Currently it is same as the first one) using an external action and the request was successful. But I do not see any table data and at the same time, i can see the page count info as in the screenshot.

Comment: So i guess, the data is hidden somewhere in the datatable.

Comment: Just a question : have you tried `table.draw();` _after_  `table.ajax.url(currentSource).load();`? This should probably be called in a timeout or a callback function. If `"draw" : "1"` not is set in the ajax response, I suspect dataTables to skip redrawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was purely my fault as a beginner in Datatable.

I put the below code mistakenly which i could not notice and It is also executed when i try to reload with new ajax request externally.

```
table.columns(dtableCols).visible(false)
```

Where dtableCols is an array of all column ids. eg: [0,1,2,3,4,5]

This caused me datatable values makes hidden and now i have removed. It is working fine. Thanks for all your suggestions.